# How to Use Multicore for This Task?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

```
xff[g, mx, m\[Psi]] = Quiet[Table[Re[x /. FindRoot[x - Log[(0.038*2*1.22*10^19*m\[Psi]*sigv[x, g, mx, m\[Psi]])/
     Sqrt[107*x]], {x, 25}]] /. {g -> matt[[i, 1]], 
 mx -> matt[[i, 2]], m\[Psi] -> matt[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, 10000000}]]
```

> This takes months while running it on my 4 core i5. But we have a facility
>   of 64 core machine. I want to parallelize this code. So need help to edit this code to use in parallelization.

Here is the entire code for a restricted calculation:

```
replace1 = {me -> 0.0, mμ -> 0.0, mτ -> 0.0, md -> 0.0, 
   ms -> 0.0, mb -> 0.0, mu -> 0.0, mc -> 0.0, mt -> 173.21, 
   mW -> 80.385, mZ -> 91.188, vev -> 246, mh -> 125};
replace = {me -> 0.000511, mμ -> 0.1057, mτ -> 1.777, 
   md -> 0.0048, ms -> 0.095, mb -> 4.18, mu -> 0.0023, mc -> 1.275, 
   mt -> 173.21, mW -> 80.385, mZ -> 91.188, vev -> 246, mh -> 125};

rulel = {nc -> 1, gfv -> 0, gfa -> -0.707 g};
ruleU = {nc -> 3, gfv -> 0.884 g, gfa -> 0};
ruleD = {nc -> 3, gfv -> 0.707 g, gfa -> 0};
ruleN = {nc -> 1, gfv -> 0.354 g, gfa -> -0.354 g};
rule1 = {gψa -> 1.7536718949856565` g, gψv -> 0};
rule2 = {gψa -> 1.7536718949856565` g, gψv -> 0};

n1 = n4 = 1/Sqrt[2] // N;
θ = 1;
g1 = 5/8 (3 n1 + n4) g;
g2 = 1/8 (3 n1 + n4) g;

g11 = g1*Cos[θ]^2 + g2*Sin[θ]^2;
g22 = g2*Cos[θ]^2 + g1*Sin[θ]^2;
g12 = g21 = Sin[2 θ]/2 (g1 - g2);

geff = 2 + 2 (1 + Δ)^(3/2) Exp[-x (Δ)];

(* Total Decay width of X: *)
Γtt1[g_, mx_] = ((3*nc*mx)/(24*π) (1)^(1/2) (gfa^2 (1) + gfv^2 (1)) /. rulel) +
                ((3 nc*mx)/(24*π) (1)^(1/2) (gfa^2 (1) + gfv^2 (1)) /. ruleN) +
                ((3*nc*mx)/(24*π) (1)^(1/2) (gfa^2 (1) + gfv^2 (1)) /. ruleU) +
                ((3*nc*mx)/(24*π) (1)^(1/2) (gfa^2 (1) + gfv^2 (1)) /. ruleD);

Γfd = 0.1828052084804079` g^2 mx;

Δ = 1;

(* Thermal cross section via integration formula: *)

sigma[x_, g_, mx_, mψ_, mf_] = 
   3/(12*π*s ((s - mx^2)^2 + mx^2*(Γfd)^2)) ((1 - 4*mf^2/s)/(1 - 4*mψ^2/s))^(1/2)*
   (gfa^2 g11^2 (4 mψ^2 (mf^2 (7 - 6 s/mx^2 + 3 s^2/mx^4) - s) +
   s (s - 4 mf^2)) + gfv^2 g11^2 (s + 2 mf^2) (s - 4 mψ^2)); /. mf -> 0

sig[x_, g_, mx_, mψ_] = (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, me] /. rulel /. replace /. rule1) +
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, mμ] /. rulel /. replace /. rule1) +
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, mτ] /. rulel /. replace /. rule1) +
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, md] /. ruleD /. replace /. rule1) +
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, md] /. ruleD /. replace /. rule1) +
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, ms] /. ruleD /. replace /. rule1) + 
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, mu] /. ruleU /. replace /. rule1) + 
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, mc] /. ruleU /. replace /. rule1) + 
                        (sigma[x, g, mx, mψ, mt] /. ruleU /. replace /. rule1);

sig1[x_, g_, mx_, mψ_] = 4/(geff)^2 (1 + 2 g12^2/g11^2 (1 + Δ)^(3/2) Exp[-x (Δ)] + 
  g22^2/g11^2 (1 + Δ)^3 Exp[-2 x (Δ)]) sig[x, g, mx, mψ];

sigv[x_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, mx_?NumericQ, mψ_?NumericQ] := 
  x/(8 mψ^5*BesselK[2, x]*BesselK[2, x]) (NIntegrate[
     sig1[x, g, mx, mψ]*s^(1/2)*BesselK[1, s^(1/2)*x/mψ], {s, 4 mψ^2, Infinity}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 2]);

(* CALCULATION OF XF: *)

matt = Tuples[{Range[0.005, 0.7, 0.02], Range[100, 5100, 500], 
    Range[100, 2600, 400]}];

Clear[xff]
xff[g, mx, mψ] = 
   Quiet[Table[
     Re[x /. FindRoot[
         x - Log[(0.038*2*1.22*10^19*mψ*sigv[x, g, mx, mψ])/
            Sqrt[107*x]], {x, 25}]] /. {g -> matt[[i, 1]], 
       mx -> matt[[i, 2]], mψ -> matt[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, 
      2695}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {3567.33,Null} *)
```

Comment: If you do the numerical substitution of the `matt` values *before* doing the `FindRoot`, not *after*, then you may not need months for this. How about rephrasing this question as "How to speed up this code?" and give an example of the first few values of the parameters necessary to run it?

Comment: Findroot takes more time, even for a single value of g, mx, m\[Psi] it takes one second. I have to find a large number of roots. So I want to use all cores of a machine. Is there a way out to break this time bound.

Comment: Again: please post complete code that actually runs, including a definition of `sigv` and `matt`, and a call to `xff` with actual parameters. The only way to experiment with your code is to have working code.

Comment: ok, it there any other plate form where I can paste the code directly

Comment: Dropbox, Pastebin, ...

Comment: Here I am attaching the link for the complete code.                                                                 https://pastebin.com/3QViHSVW.  Although I have taken here a lesser number of points to check my code.

Comment: The "Quiet" in xff is covering up a host of problems. The integration is not converging well. For the following I picked a sample value for i (100). Try Plot[x-Log[(0.038*2*1.22*10^19*matt[[100,3]]*sigv[x,matt[[100,1]], matt[[100,2]],matt[[100,3]]])/Sqrt[107*x]], {x,0.05,7}]. Given that form, it is no surprise that FindFit is having trouble. Plott just sigv from x=1.2 to x=1.25. Then calculate sigv at x=1.2 and x=1.215. Note that you get a failure to converge at 1.2, but not at 1.215. Given the continuity, that suggests that most of your sigv calcs are wrong due to a failure to converge.

Comment: Dear Kevin, what can be done to calculate the sigv correctly.